# angularjs password confirmation not display confirmation message

Tags: angularjs

Please help me why im not able to display confirmation message

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .directive('pwCheck', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
            require: '?ngModel',

            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                var val2 = "";
                scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function () {
                    validate();
                })
                attr.$observe('pwCheck', function (val) {
                    validate();
                });
                var validate = function () {
                    var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
                    var val2 = attr.pwCheck;
                    ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', val1 === val2);
```

**HtmlCode**

Here im trying to validate `Emp_Password` against  `Emp_Cpsw`    for that i used `EmpCpsw`  directive.The directive working Good but confirmation message is not popup

```
<b>EnterPassword</b> :<input type="password" name="Emp_Password" ng-model="psw1" pw-check="{{psw2}}" required />

                <span class="error" ng-show="pwCheck">Password not match</span>
                <b>c_password</b><input type="password" name="Emp_Cpsw" ng-model="psw2" pw-check required pw-check="{{psw1}}" />           
                <span class="error" ng-show="pwCheck">Password not match</span>
```

Comment: use, `passwordVerify`, `<span class="error" ng-show="passwordVerify">Password not match</span>`

Comment: @sravan its working thanks a lot

Comment: I have added as an answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `setValidity` with name `passwordVerify` so should use the same name in your `view`.

```
ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', val1 === val2);
```

So, use

```
<span class="error" ng-show="passwordVerify">Password not match</span>
```